# Prove the following equality with determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Show that
> $$
> \begin{vmatrix}
> b_1+c_1 & c_1+a_1& a_1+b_1 \\
> b_2+c_2 & c_2+a_2 & a_2+b_2 \\
> b_3+c_3 & c_3+a_3 & a_3+b_3 \\
> \end{vmatrix}
>  =
> 2\begin{vmatrix}
> a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
> a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
> a_3 & b_3 & c_3
> \end{vmatrix} 
> $$

I can only see the brute-force approach. However, it really seems to have a more attractive and smarter way, but cannot find how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the 9th property https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQqohwBSs6jwvPTEc3lzGfUXtnGpJBKm2d1ufhOfLLTe6UbsqBz&usqp=CAU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to illustrate what @RobertIsrael pointed out: since$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
b_{1}+c_{1} & c_{1}+a_{1} & a_{1}+b_{1}\\
b_{2}+c_{2} & c_{2}+a_{2} & a_{2}+b_{2}\\
b_{3}+c_{3} & c_{3}+a_{3} & a_{3}+b_{3}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{1} & b_{1} & c_{1}\\
a_{2} & b_{2} & c_{2}\\
a_{3} & b_{3} & c_{3}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right),$$we need only calculate$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right|=-\left|\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right|+\left|\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right|=1+1=2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $A$ is the matrix on the right, matrix on the left is $AB$ for a certain $B$.

Comment: Wouldn't that take longer to find?

Comment: @AshWhole Longer than what? It's much quicker than VIVID's approach, as my answer shows. But if you know a quicker way, e.g. with the property you linked to, it'd be lovely to see an answer going through it.

Comment: @J.G., I thought of separating the Determinant (many would lead to 0 that way) but it's slightly hefty. Martund, has an even better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Apply
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
b_1+c_1 & c_1+a_1& a_1+b_1 \\
b_2+c_2 & c_2+a_2 & a_2+b_2 \\
b_3+c_3 & c_3+a_3 & a_3+b_3 \\
\end{vmatrix}
 =&\ \ 
\begin{vmatrix}
2(a_1+b_1+c_1) & c_1+a_1 & a_1+b_1\\
2(a_2+b_2+c_2) & c_2+a_2 & a_2+b_2 \\
2(a_3+b_3+c_3) & c_3+a_3 & a_3+b_3
\end{vmatrix}\\
=&2\begin{vmatrix}
a_1+b_1+c_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2+b_2+c_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3+b_3+c_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{vmatrix}\\
=&2\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}
**EXPLANATION**

1. $C_1=C_1+C_2+C_3$
2. $C_2=C_1-C_2$ , $C_3=C_1-C_3$
3. $C_1=C_1-C_2-C_3$

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Comment: @VIVID, You're welcome :)